# Event handler memory leak using ChildWindows

Tags: c#, silverlight, events

I just want to ensure that the code below will not be causing the ChildWindow Login in this case to never be collected by the GC. Just to clarify the sample this comes from a silverlight page that is inherited by all other pages therefore the virtual void pageloaded method.

```
public class MyPage : Page
{
    // Executes when the user navigates to this page.
    protected override void OnNavigatedTo(NavigationEventArgs e)
    {
        _user = App.AuthenticatedUser;
        if (!_user.IsValid)
        {
            Login loginWindow = new Login(_user);
            loginWindow.Closed += new EventHandler(PageLoaded);
            loginWindow.Show();
        }
        else
            PageLoaded(this, e);
    }

    //to be overridden by the pages extending this page control
    protected virtual void PageLoaded(object sender, EventArgs e) { }
```

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fine. The loginWindows's Close event knows of your handler, not the other way around, so the form will not have any ties preventing the GC from picking it up.

Unregistering event handlers becomes important if the object your event is defined on will persist in the application for a long time (and you do not want the event handler association to persist for the same duration).